# Entity framework context in using block

Tags: entity-framework, exception

I am writing a service layer application, which interacts with database using Entity framework.

I am enclosing my individual "unit-of-work" in a using block, where I initialise my data context.

However I need to throw some exceptions, to convey database errors to applications, which are using my service application. So I am doing something like this:

```
using (dbcontext = new DbContext())
{
 throw new Exception("Error while Saving data");
}
```

Can anyone confirm if this is Ok? Will Entity framework data context be disposed off correctly even after an exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block is converted to a `try/finally` block when compiling with disposing logic inside the `finally` block.

However your exception will not be thrown outside if the `Dispose` method throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is correct. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> A using statement can be exited either when the end of the using
>   statement is reached or if an exception is thrown and control leaves
>   the statement block before the end of the statement.

That being said, I would throw a more specific exception than the `Exception` one.

Comment: Thanks Ken. Yes I will be using a more specific exception in reality :)